# Как изменить цвет label при нажатии на checkBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на `checkBox` нужно изменить цвет текста в `label` на красный. Текст хранится в `textbox2`. После нажатия на `checkBox` цвет изменяется, но если уберу галочку, то цвет не меняется на тот, который в текстБоксе. Как это исправить? Вот код:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != null)
        {
            label1.Text = textBox2.Text;
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        else { MessageBox.Show("Введите текст!"); }
    }

    else { label1.Text = textBox2.Text; }
}
```

Comment: традиционный вопрос — WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @VladD, а тут значение имеет? человек красит в один цвет и забывает перекрашивать обратно. Хотяяя, мож в WPF есть что и автоматическое

Comment: @Dmitry: Разумеется. В WPF правильнее делать не так, а через привязку и триггеры.

Comment: @VladD, а, разумно

Comment: @VladD, а по именам не видно, что winforms?

Comment: @Qwertiy хотя да :) `MessageBox.Show("Введите текст!");`

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, это ж надо просканировать все имена, мне лень. Вроде, всё, кроме `ForeColor`, подходит и туда, и туда.

Comment: @Dmitry: `MessageBox` вроде бы есть и там, и там.

Comment: @VladD есть, но как мне помнится по разному дергается

Comment: @Dmitry: Точно, там надо ещё окно указывать (но можно `null`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598678%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Да лааадно - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598674(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Monk ну даже если и так, то в любом случае не так: `showMessageBoxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` а вот так: `button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @Dmitry: А вот это уже по идее всё равно, имя процедуры каждый выбирает себе как хочет. Я, например, лучше застрелюсь, чем назову кнопку `button4` в своём коде.

Comment: @VladD про кнопку согласен, но что делать с аргументами?

Comment: @Dmitry: А, типы аргументов разные! Только что заметил. Вы правы, да. Но всё же, возвращаясь к началу ветки дискуссии — авторы вопросов не должны заставлять отвечающих знать _такие_ тонкости.

Comment: @VladD, а ну это да, играть в экстрасенса как бы не наше занятие

Answer (score 2):

Невнимательность, вот в чем причина, забыли перекрасить в нужный цвет, когда галка снята:

```
Color colorInit = Color.Black;

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkBox1.Checked)
     {
         if (textBox2.Text != null)
         {
             label1.Text = textBox2.Text;
             label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
         }
         else 
         { 
             MessageBox.Show("Введите текст!"); }
         }
    }
    else 
    { 
        label1.Text = textBox2.Text;
        label1.ForeColor = colorInit;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочли мой вопрос) Если у меня в текстБоксе будут синие слова, то как быть? Допустим текстБокс заполняется рандомным цветом, при нажатии на чекБокс, изменить надо на красный, при снятии галочки - обратно на цвет текстБокса. Это можно как-то сделать?

Comment: @inkorpus, да, запомнить цвет которым было проинициализировано поле

Comment: ну вот, я и спрашиваю - как это сделать?)

Comment: всё, сделал) label1.ForeColor = textBox2.ForeColor;

Comment: @inkorpus поправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

В коде была ошибка при проверке того, есть ли текст в текстБоксе или нет, вот исправленный код с изменением цвета, вдруг кому пригодится

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите текст!");
            }

            else label1.Text = textBox2.Text;
            label1.ForeColor = textBox2.ForeColor;

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                if (textBox2.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Введите текст!");
                }

                else
                    label1.Text = textBox2.Text;
                label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
```